# How to determine the sequence of ordering certificates by browser?

Tags: https, security-certificate, browsers, authentication, centos

I did a Mutual Certificate Authentication implementation with OpenSSL and Apache Web Server on CentOS platform. To simple explanation see this diagram:

> ---
>
> ```
>                 ----------
>               |  Root CA  |    // Self-Signed Certificate
>                 ----------
>                     |      
>                 ----------
>               |  SiteA CA  |  // Intermediate Certificate signed by Root CA
>                 ----------
>                |          |
>            --------    --------
>          | Server1 | | Client1 |  //Certificates signed by SiteA CA
>            --------    --------
> ```
>
> ---

in Apache Configuration I edited next: 
make a chain crt:

```
sudo cat server.crt rootca.crt serverCA.crt > server_chain.crt
```

edit ssl config :

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

edit those four lines :

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/server.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/server.key 
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/server_chain.crt 
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/rootca.crt
```

and to make it (two-way) Mutual Authentication :

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  10
```

Then : restart apache=httpd service :

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

you know that you should give your browser root ca certificate and client certificate and while I was doing a Testing I did next:

I removed `rootca.crt` from browser and noticed that Firefox and Chrome ask me for client certificate confirmation before telling me that the server is not a trusted, while Opera browser acts right, first tell me that it's not trusted and then show me Client certificate information.

I was told that in IIS there's an option for telling the web server which one to ask about first, but I couldn't find that option here in Apache.
Can anybody help ?

Comment: For general SSL, when you chain certs together the most immediate cert is first in the file.  Your ultimate root cert is last in the file.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yourwebsite.com

I recently used this to test security. This returns which protocals are used, possible vulnarebilities, keylengths and **certificate chain order**.

They give you all sorts of information, very useful, I recommend this for everyone, just do a simple check, it's free and only takes a few minutes.